# How to change gitk language (on a Mac)?

Tags: macos, gitk

I cannot find an option in the Preferences menu to change the language. I know it has to be done somewhere else, from a terminal window I think, but I don't remember the commands. 
How can I change gitk interface messages language ?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information available on [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=66):

> Tk picks up the language as defined in
>   the Region and Language control panel
>   item

In Mac OS X, you should define the `LANG` variable. You can do this with something like:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

If you want to see the gitk GUI in English.

Answer (score 0):

If git was installed with Homebrew you can rename the language file of gitk and git gui in these places:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/git-gui/2.32.0/share/gitk/lib/msgs
/usr/local/Cellar/git-gui/2.32.0/share/git-gui/lib/msgs
```

Just rename the language file you don't want to use to something else, e.g.:

```
mv de.msg de.msg.bak
```

You might need to redo this when git is updated.